# Unable to click expand button using selenium web driver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm totally new to programming. Currently trying to automate few daily tasks using selenium web driver on Python. I have a webpage which contains **multiple + expand button**. Below is the code

Without expansion:

```
<div class="expansion container">
    <div class="expansion_base_parent"></div> 
    <div class="expansion expansion_parent"> 
        <button type="button" class="compact-visual-toggle"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

With expansion

```
<div class="expansion_container">
    <div class="expansion_base_parent"></div> 
    <div class="expansion expansion_parent"> 
        <button type="button" class="compact-visual-toggle active"></button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm unable to find this element using any of the find_by method
My colleague said the page contains json that's why unable to locate using find_by

Can somebody please help with the code to locate and click the expand button.

Actual page:
Go-to https://fortigate.fortidemo.com
Username demo
Password demo
Click login read-only
Click later in next window
Now navigate to Network > interfaces There you can see lot of expand button that's what I'm referring I have written code to come till this page, but I want to expand before taking screenshot of the page

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML source or URL for the element?

Comment: Additionally share us your code part where the error is happening.

Comment: Sorry I added somehow it missed.               Without expansion
<div class="expansion container"><div class="expansion_base_parent"></div> <div class="expansion expansion parent">

<button type="button" class="compact-visual-toggle"></button></div></div>


With expansion
<div class="expansion container"><div class="expansion_base_parent"></div> <div class="expansion expansion_parent">

<button type="button" class="compact-visual-toggle active"></button></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to do anything with JSON.

See, you are saying

```
<div class="expansion container">
    <div class="expansion_base_parent"></div> 
    <div class="expansion expansion_parent"> 
        <button type="button" class="compact-visual-toggle"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

that you see this HTML when expand button is present.

You can locate with below css :-

```
button.compact-visual-toggle
```

or xpath :

```
//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')]
```

and since you have mentioned that they are multiple expension button, you can differentiate like below :

```
(//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')])[1]
```

should represent the first, for second you can try :

```
(//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')])[2]
```

and so on.. for 3rd, 4th....

in code you can use it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')]").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')])[1]").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')])[2]").click()
```

Now, coming to second part :

```
<div class="expansion_container">
    <div class="expansion_base_parent"></div> 
    <div class="expansion expansion_parent"> 
        <button type="button" class="compact-visual-toggle active"></button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

in you you want to un-expand it, you could use the below xpath :

```
//button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle active')]
```

and use it like above.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response....still the same issue.....it says selenium.common.exception.NoSuchElementException

Comment: I tried css and xpath method,.  button.compact-visual-toggle   //button[contains(@class, 'compact-visual-toggle')]

Comment: Can you share Page URL, if public ? if not, the You need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: Go-to https://fortigate.fortidemo.com
Username demo
Password demo
Click login read-only
Click later in next window
Now navigate to Network > interfaces
There you can see lot of expand button that's what I'm referring
I have written code to come till this page, but I want to expand before taking screenshot of the page

Comment: Hi team, Anybody got on chance to review the page.....is it worth a try with the Selenium webdriver library..... currently I'm trying to automate our firewalls checks, and this is only blocking point for me......can somebody confirm whether it's possible to click the expand button or not,. As I mentioned I'm very much new to programming.....so expecting your advise please

Comment: Can somebody please confirm if it is even possible to try with Python?